# Netty http/2 multipart body decoder

Tags: java, netty, http2

I'm creating an http/2 webserver in java using netty. For http/1.1 there is an `HttpPostRequestDecoder` to decode multipart http request bodies.

The API for this class only supports the http/1.1 `HttpRequest` classes, no raw `ByteBuf`s like we get in the `Http2FrameListener.onDataRead` handler.

Is there a way in netty to decode http/2 multipart bodies using an equivalent of the `HttpPostRequestDecoder`?